# Why does the output voltage of this rectifier only reach 45V?

Tags: power-supply, power, diodes, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice

I'm trying to learn how to design a switched mode power supply.

As a first step, I want to build a rectifier to convert 230 VAC to DC. To help me design, I made the simple LTspice circuit shown in the picture below.

The problem is that the output DC voltage only rises to 45 V.

The diodes I've used for the model are [RBQ30NS45A](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/diode/schottky_barrier/rbq30ns45atl-e.pdf) Schottky diodes (as can be seen in the schematic). These have a maximum reverse voltage of 45 V.

Is this the problem? Why does this cause the voltage to clamp at 45 V? If this is the problem, can anyone recommend diodes to use instead?

I want to design a supply that could drive a 1.5 - 2 kW load if possible.

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Result of simulation:

[image: Result of simulation]

Answer (score 4):

The rectifier diodes must hold least twice to peak voltage on the input. So get a diode that holds at leat 800V, better 1200V to have some headroom. There is no reason to use schottky diodes in a rectifier in such a system.

Why, you might ask.
Because you will have +Vpeak at the ouput of the diode when the input voltage goes to -Vpeak.

But there are two diodes "in series" in that path, you might say.
That's true, but keep in mind that you can't ensure, that those two diodes have exactly the same leakage current and share the reverse voltage evenly.

If your AC voltage is 240V nominal you can get up the 264V with the tolerances. This leads to a peak voltage (Vpeak) of 373V. Multiply by 2 and you get 746V. And this is without sudden voltage spikes.

My suggestion is to look up Application Notes for Switch mode power supplies that different suppliers procvide. Read them carfully and follow the design adive you get there.

For example with this one: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5264-evl400weupl7-400w-smps-demonstration-board-stmicroelectronics.pdf

If you're not really experienced with electronics don't (and I mean DON'T!!) try such a project. It's working with mains voltage (dangerous), high DC voltages (even more dangerous), high current (can make stuff really hot really quickly, dangerous!) and feedback loops (which can make diagnosing errors a huge pain). Also, mistakes can blow up everythign within seconds.

Start with low voltage, low current stuff to learn the basics. And than, when you're absolutely comfortable with working with low power stuff slowly start to go into higher voltage stuff. Still plenty of stuff than can go wrong there but at least it won't kill you or cost your eyesight!

Answer (score 2):

Those diodes have a reverse voltage at 45V. This means that, if you apply more than 45V on the diode's anode (where in your case, you try to apply a maximum of ~300V like this):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcIINP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It will start conducting current! Reverse voltage on a diode, is the voltage that will make the diode conduct when its the Kathode voltage is 45V greater than the anode voltage.

Diodes don't only conduct current from anode to cathode. The reverse polarity has a breakdown voltage as well. Its just way greater than the forward breakdown voltage.

You will need to find a diode that has a reverse voltage greater than 300V.

Comment: This kind of behavior (clamp at breakdown) is seen mostly in simulations. Diode becomes short circuit is code for blown up diodes.